# TikZ circle size

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please which keys may I use to get the circles in the following two categories of the same size? `minimum size` and `inner sep` don't improve the output. Please, if needed, use any looping macro of your choice.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,thick}]
\foreach \x/\y in {a/{-1,-2},b/{1,-2},c/{2,-1},d/{2,1},e/{1,2},
  f/{-1,2},g/{-2,1},h/{-2,-1}}{
  \node (\x) at (\y) [fill=blue!20,draw=yellow] {\x};
}
\foreach \x/\y {a/b,b/c,c/d,d/e,e/f,f/g,g/h,h/a}{
  \draw [->] (\x)--(\y) node [midway,fill=red!20,draw=blue,] {\x--\y};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should all circles have the same size or are there two sizes for the two categories?

Comment: For me `minimum width=<length>` works. Or do you want to accomplish something different?

Comment: There's no solution as it obviously depends on the height and (in this case) more importantly the width of what's in the nodes. It the width is small, adding a `\strut` may help. A `minimum width=` as a style may also solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following examples I have replaced `\foxloop` (package `ltxtools`), because it causes an error message. Also I have increased the scaling factor to reduce overlappings.

The examples uses the loops two times. In the first loop the maximal box dimensions of the node contents are calculated. (Update: Missing `\tempDimBox` added for the nodes with `\x--\y`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\tempDimWD
\newdimen\tempDimHT
\newdimen\tempDimDP
\newcommand*{\tempDimBox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\makebox[\tempDimWD]{#1}}%
    \ht0=\tempDimHT
    \dp0=\tempDimDP
    \usebox0 %
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\tempDimMeasure}[3]{%
  \node at (0,0) {%
    \global\tempDimWD=0pt
    \global\tempDimHT=0pt
    \global\tempDimDP=0pt
    \foreach #1 in #2 {%
      \sbox0{#3}%
      \ifdim\wd0>\tempDimWD
        \global\tempDimWD=\wd0 %
      \fi
      \ifdim\ht0>\tempDimHT
        \global\tempDimHT=\ht0
      \fi
      \ifdim\dp0>\tempDimDP
        \global\tempDimDP=\dp0
      \fi
    }%
  };%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % scale=.8,
  auto=left,
  every node/.style={circle,thick},
]
\def\yellowlist{%
  a/{-1,-2},b/{1,-2},c/{2,-1},d/{2,1},e/{1,2},f/{-1,2},g/{-2,1},h/{-2,-1}%
}
\def\bluelist{a/b,b/c,c/d,d/e,e/f,f/g,g/h,h/a}

\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\yellowlist}{\x}%
\foreach \x/\y in \yellowlist {
   \node (\x) at (\y) [fill=blue!20,draw=yellow] {\tempDimBox{\x}};
}

\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\bluelist}{\x--\y}
\foreach \x/\y in \bluelist {
  \draw [->] (\x) -- (\y) node [midway,fill=red!20,draw=blue,] {\tempDimBox{\x--\y}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % scale=.8,
  scale=1.2,
  auto=left,
  every node/.style={circle,thick},
]
\def\yellowlist{%
  a/{-1,-2},b/{1,-2},c/{2,-1},d/{2,1},e/{1,2},f/{-1,2},g/{-2,1},h/{-2,-1}%
}
\def\bluelist{a/b,b/c,c/d,d/e,e/f,f/g,g/h,h/a}

%\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\yellowlist}{\x}% Since we're looking for largest circle.
\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\bluelist}{\x--\y}
\foreach \x/\y in \yellowlist {
   \node (\x) at (\y) [fill=blue!20,draw=yellow] {\tempDimBox{\x}};
}
\foreach \x/\y in \bluelist {
  \draw [->] (\x) -- (\y)
  node [midway,fill=red!20,draw=blue] {\tempDimBox{\x--\y}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A variant, where the nodes `a` to `h` are on the vertices of a regular octagon.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\tempDimWD
\newdimen\tempDimHT
\newdimen\tempDimDP
\newcommand*{\tempDimBox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\makebox[\tempDimWD]{#1}}%
    \ht0=\tempDimHT
    \dp0=\tempDimDP
    \usebox0 %
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\tempDimMeasure}[3]{%
  \node at (0,0) {%
    \global\tempDimWD=0pt
    \global\tempDimHT=0pt
    \global\tempDimDP=0pt
    \foreach #1 in #2 {%
      \sbox0{#3}%
      \ifdim\wd0>\tempDimWD
        \global\tempDimWD=\wd0 %
      \fi
      \ifdim\ht0>\tempDimHT
        \global\tempDimHT=\ht0
      \fi
      \ifdim\dp0>\tempDimDP
        \global\tempDimDP=\dp0
      \fi
    }%
  };%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % scale=.8,
  auto=left, 
  every node/.style={circle,thick},
]
\def\yellowlist{a,...,h}
\def\bluelist{a/b,b/c,c/d,d/e,e/f,f/g,g/h,h/a}

\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\yellowlist}{\x}%
\foreach [count=\xi] \x in \yellowlist {
  \node (\x) at ({180+360/16+360/8*\xi:2})
  [fill=blue!20,draw=yellow] {\tempDimBox{\x}};
}

\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\bluelist}{\x--\y}
\foreach \x/\y in \bluelist {
  \draw [->] (\x) -- (\y) node [midway,fill=red!20,draw=blue,] {\tempDimBox{\x--\y}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % scale=.8,
  scale=1.2, 
  auto=left, 
  every node/.style={circle,thick},
]
\def\yellowlist{a,...,h}
\def\bluelist{a/b,b/c,c/d,d/e,e/f,f/g,g/h,h/a}

%\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\yellowlist}{\x}% Since we're looking for largest circle.
\tempDimMeasure{\x/\y}{\bluelist}{\x--\y}
\foreach [count=\xi] \x/\y in \yellowlist {
  \node (\x) at ({180+360/16+360/8*\xi:2}) 
  [fill=blue!20,draw=yellow] {\tempDimBox{\x}};
}
\foreach \x/\y in \bluelist {
  \draw [->] (\x) -- (\y)
  node [midway,fill=red!20,draw=blue] {\tempDimBox{\x--\y}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Heiko solves Ahmed's problem.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Many thanks. I see that circle `(e-f)` is smaller, or is it my screen or eyes that give me that impression? Master Heiko knows the macros in all CTAN packages.:). I defined `\foxloop` in more one place. I should correct that. Thanks.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I had forgotten to add `\tempDimBox` for the nodes with `\x--\y`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: The best way I can ask this question is to edit your answer. Please let me know if I have done any harm there.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Yes, two `\tempDimMeasuer` after each other do not make sense, because the second resets the dimen registers at the beginning. And since all single letters of the smaller nodes `\x` are also contained in the larger nodes `\x--\y`, the line can just be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

a solution which also uses two polygons

command `\GrapheBoucle[0.8]{8}{a, b​​, c, d, e, f, g, h}{ab, bc, cd,, ef, fg, gh, ha}{4.5cm}` 
generates two polygons are angularly offset

- The first apex to the terms of the first list `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}`, such summit are connected by arcs,
- The second peaks correspond to the second list `{ab, bc, cd,, ef, fg, gh, ha}`
- The radius of the circle passing through the vertices of the first polygon is specified by the last parameter `{4.5cm}`
- The first parameter (optional) `[0.8]` is a draft ratio which is used to specify the radius of the second polygon with respect to the first.
- The second parameter `{8}`, the number of vertices of polygons

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
enter code here
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,patterns,snakes,decorations,chains,fit}
\newcommand{\GrapheBoucle}[5][0.8]{
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=#2, minimum size=#5,rotate=180](sommet) at (0,0) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=#2, minimum size={#5*#1},rotate={180+(180)/#2}](lien) at (0,0)  {};
\pgfmathparse{180/(#2+1)}
\foreach \i in {1,...,#2}{
\node (LGraphe\i) at (lien.corner \i){};
}
\begin{scope}[start chain=graphe placed {at=(sommet.corner \tikzchaincount)}, every join/.style={bend right=\pgfmathresult},->]
\foreach \i in {#3}{
\node [on chain,join, circle, draw,fill=blue!20,draw=yellow](NGraphe\tikzchaincount) {\i};
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=noeud placed {at=(lien.corner \tikzchaincount)}, every join/.style={bend right=\pgfmathresult}]
\foreach \i in {#4}{
\node [on chain, circle, draw,fill=red!20,draw=blue](NGraphe\tikzchaincount) {\i};
}

\end{scope}
\draw (graphe-end) to[bend right={\pgfmathresult}] (graphe-begin);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GrapheBoucle[0.8]{8}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}{a-b,b-c,c-d,d-e,e-f,f-g,g-h,h-a}{4.5cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, my answer does not address the problem